# Is it a good idea to keep a backport entry in /etc/apt/sources.list ? For updates and especially upgrades ? No side effects?

Tags: debian, backports

I have to install a `nVidia` driver for my video card on a `Debian 9.8 Linux-4.9.0.9-amd64`.

I have to add a backport for that :
`deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free`

But this means that other updates or upgrades I will do in the later months will see and use this line from the `sources.list` file and will use it, often, as new coming or updated components will appear that my default `Debian 9.8` currently doesn't have.

Won't this cause instability ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this won't update any other packages if you install your backport packages using

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t stretch-backports install packagename
```

The backports repository has a priority of 100 while the standard repos have a priority of 500 (higher), so packages get only installed or updated from the default repos, unless they’ve been installed explicitly from backports or are only available in backports.

You can list the priorities of your sources with `apt-cache policy`.

What you shouldn't do is an `upgrade` to stretch-backports (`apt-get upgrade` with `-t stretch-backports`).

See: [Debian Backports Instructions](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @StephenKitt, this makes it much clearer!