# Debian stretch not getting package from stretch-backports

Tags: debian, apt

[This page](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/freetds-dev) shows that the freetds-dev version on stretch-backports is at `1.00.104-1~bpo9+1` but when I attempt to install it I get version `0.91-6.1+b4`.

```
root@c0884c37efdc:/# apt update
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                                                                                                       
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                
Get:4 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease [91.8 kB]
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                         
Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release             
Get:8 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages [593 kB]
Fetched 685 kB in 6s (112 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.


root@c0884c37efdc:/# apt install freetds-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
freetds-dev is already the newest version (0.91-6.1+b4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Why would apt not be getting the 1.0.0 version of freetds-dev?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the [stable version](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/freetds-dev). You need to run `apt -t stretch-backports install freetds-dev`.

Related:
[Is it a good idea to keep a backport entry in /etc/apt/sources.list ? For updates and especially upgrades ? No side effects?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516240/is-it-a-good-idea-to-keep-a-backport-entry-in-etc-apt-sources-list-for-update/516243#516243)