# Getting packages from debian backports not working as documented

Tags: debian, apt, backports

Before dear community marks this question as duplicate please known that I've done site search and figured out there is no equivalent duplicate, for instance this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516664/debian-stretch-not-getting-package-from-stretch-backports) is not duplicate

I have followed the following instructions:

- https://wiki.debian.org/Backports
- https://backports.debian.org/Instructions

According to these instructions step No.1 is to update `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding the following line:

- `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports main contrib non-free`

When this step is done we need up update index by running `sudo apt update`

From this point on we have two options:

1. Explicitly install a package from backports, for example

- `apt install -t bookworm-backports <package>`

2. Implicitly install a package from backports

- `apt install <package>/bookworm-backports`

There is a significant difference between those 2 methods!

The first method will install package from backports but will also pull in all it's dependencides also from backports including their dpenedencies and so on which results in "bloated" installation of a package.

The second method is cleaner, better and recommended by debian because unlike first method it will reuse dependencies (from main, not from backports) and will pull in only the main package being installed that is from backports.

In other words second method will reuse dependencies that are alaready insalled on system without downloading them.
However under certain circumstances if that's not possible it will pull dependencies from backports (in rare scenarios though)

The problem I'm having is that first method with `-t` options always works while the second method never works at all.

I want to know why that is and how can I make the second method work?

Here are two examples that are reproducible for you to test:

```
sudo apt install wine/bookworm-backports
sudo apt install passwordsafe/bookworm-backports
```

Here is the output from first example:

> sudo apt install wine/bookworm-backports

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is a virtual package provided by:
  wine 8.0~repack-4
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Release 'bookworm-backports' for 'wine' was not found
```

As you can see `bookworm-backports` was not found!

However if you run with `-t` option you can confirm this is false:

`sudo apt install wine -t bookworm-backports`

Which will work just fine and offer you to install the package.

So the question is very simple, why doesn't second method (without the `-t` option) not work and what do I need to do to make it work, do I do something wrong?

---

For additional information I'm using Debian 12 (bookworm)

And my `sources.list` looks like this:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main

deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main

deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-backports main
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-backports main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your specific `wine` installation attempt, the reason it fails is that [`wine`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/wine) isn’t available in `bookworm-backports`.

Your more general confusion is understandable; there’s one missing piece of information, and that’s the [pin priority](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/apt_preferences.5) associated with backports. The backports repository has a default priority of 100, which ensures that a backports package is never a candidate for upgrade or installation instead of the same package from a stable repository.

Thus, when you ask `apt` to install a package using `/bookworm-backports`, if that package is backported, it will be selected, but any dependency will then be evaluated using priority rules. A version of the package in the stable repositories will always end up with a higher priority than the backported version (if any), and will be chosen. In some scenarios `apt` will consider versioned requirements from backports instead, but that won’t work in all cases — in particular, it fails with `wine` (on Debian 11, `apt install wine/bullseye-backports` doesn’t resolve all its dependencies, whereas `apt install -t bullseye-backports wine` does).

`apt -t bookworm-backports` on the other hand changes the priority of `bookworm-backports` to 990 temporarily, ensuring that backported packages are candidates for installation and/or upgrade. As you say, this can result in upgrading more packages than strictly necessary; however in practice that’s not usually a problem, because few library packages are backported. In any case, backported packages *replace* their original versions from the stable repositories, so the resulting bloat is minimal.

The end result of all this is that you should

1. check that the package you want is actually backported (`apt policy wine`);
2. try to install it using `/bookworm-backports`;
3. if that fails, install it using `-t bookworm-backports`.

Comment: I understand your stpes and have done it but according to this link, the wine from backports does exist and is version 9, same applies to password safe program: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=sid&keywords=wine how is then possible that it's not shown by `apt plicy <package>`?

Comment: @metablaster wrong link (sid is not bookworm-backports). The bookworm-backports search link is: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bookworm-backports&keywords=wine and there's no wine package there.

Comment: Yep, backports includes "testing" branch and also `In a few cases, usually for security updates, backports are also created from the Debian unstable distribution` aka `sid` but obviously `wine` is not security update so everything is clear now! thank you very much! I misread that

Comment: @metablaster not quite, packages have to be in testing before they can be made available in backports (with some exceptions for security fixes), but only a small subset of packages is backported. You have to specifically look for packages in backports, not testing.